# Magento 2 - Custom Maintenance Page Error - Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled

Tags: magento2, local.xml, maintenance

**Steps**

- Go into the pub/errors
- Create a copy of the local.xml.sample and rename it as local.xml
- Edit the  with custom name. Ex – **mytheme**

**local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<skin>mytheme</skin>
</config
```

Create a copy of the '**default**' folder and rename it with skin name. Ex – **mytheme**

Locate the **503.phtml** inside the newly created folder and add custom code. Add the styles inside css/styles.css and relevant images under images folder.

**Enable maintenance mode**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Error

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled.
```

- Is this the correct approach to display custom maintenance page. Magento ver. **2.2.0** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have your site in developer mode, switch it to production mode and you will see the 503.phtml page displayed.

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

Comment: add the `-s` flag to skip compilation and quickly enter production mode